# List /network-activity methods under Network Methods in the documentation

Tags: bug, feature-request, documentation, users

The API methods [`/users/{id}/network-activity`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-network-activity) and [`/me/network-activity`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-network-activity), both return a summary of a user's activity across the Stack Exchange network and do not take a `site` parameter.

They are currently [listed](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/) under **Per-site methods** → **Users**; they should be listed under **Network Methods** → **Users** instead, just like `/users/{ids}/associated` and `/users/{ids}/merges`.

The sub-header clearly states the difference between:

> #### Per-Site Methods
>
> Each of these methods operates on a single site at a time, identified by the site parameter. This parameter can be the full domain name (ie. "stackoverflow.com"), or a short form identified by api_site_parameter on the site object.

and

> #### Network Methods
>
> These methods return data across the entire Stack Exchange network of sites. Accordingly, you do not pass a site parameter to them.